# How to?: defining cv::Mat as class member and then modify it in source code file

Tags: c++, class, opencv, smart-pointers, mat

I defined a class which has a cv::Mat data member. Then in a class method I wish to modify this matrix somehow (change values, adding rows/cols, etc).

However, I keep getting a Segmentation Fault error (I'll put the errors at the bottom).

I thought about using cv::Mat& reference instead of cv::Mat as data member of the class, but then it becomes 'messy' because they have to be initialized.

I suspect I have to use smart pointers somehow but my background is more in C rather than C++.

If someone can give a step by step explanation I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

```
//Header file
class A
{
     public:
         A();
         void do_something();

     private:
         cv::Mat data;
}

//Source code file
#include "A.h"

A::A():data(cv::Mat()){}

void A::do_something()
{
   cv::Mat tmp(2,2,CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(6));
   data = tmp;
   //also other mehtods fail like
   //data = tmp.clone();
   //data.push_back(2);
}
```

Segmentation fault errors I get:

- When using data = (to some other matrix)

  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  0x00000000004051cc in cv::Mat::release (this=0x0) at
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:366
      if( refcount && CV_XADD(refcount, -1) == 1 )
- When I use for example: data.push_back(value)

  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  0x00000000004056cf in cv::Mat::push_back (this=0x0, elem=@0x7fffffffdb2c: 6) at 
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:684
      if( !data )

Comment: your code is valid. (and cv::Mat *is* already a smartpointer). also, you don't need to initialize the data Mat, that is done automatically alerady.

Comment: The code compiles, but I get the errors I posted while running. Any suggestion why is happening?

Comment: The code compiles, but I get the errors I posted while running. Any suggestion why is it happening? Also I was initializing cv::Mat because there was a compilation error like: "A::data does not have class type"... but now it's working without initialization

Comment: A::A():data(){} will call the default constructor of cvMat, you don't need a temporary inside

Comment: I wrote `A a;a.do_something();` in the main function and your program works fine. (opencv 2.4, OSX)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for the help of everybody who replied; they made me somehow notice my mistake. And an apology because it was very dumb.

The problem was that in my main function in test.cpp, I declared a pointer to class A, but I was not initializing it with the 'new' command. So I guess data cv::Mat was not initialized properly causing the Segmentation Fault.

```
//test.cpp
#include "A.h" 

int main()
{
    A* a;
    //a = new A(); //this line was missing in my program
    a->do_something();

    return 0;
}
```